# Using data in data saver mode on Android-N

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat

I have a question about data saver mode on Android N version.

If users use network data on a specific application about carrier service, it won't be charged costs of data even though connected on cellular data network.

Because carrier have not charged on their applications that provide information about using one's services.

But devices using data saver mode will be restricted for using applications or widgets though network is free.

Is there any way to avoid on data restriction except setting in a white list? or to let system know that it is free network on specific app, so don't restrict network communicate on this app?

Do applications have to be compiled with android N version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there any way to avoid on data restriction except setting in a white list?

For pre-installed apps, it is possible that a device manufacturer might add apps to the whitelist based upon particular carrier agreements. However, since the carrier can change the billing rules whenever the carrier wants, this would not be a good idea.

> or to let system know that it is free network on specific app, so don't restrict network communicate on this app?

No, because then every developer would do that.

> Do applications have to be compiled with android N version?

The behavior of Data Saver has nothing to do with your `compileSdkVersion` or (AFAIK) your `targetSdkVersion`. If you want to work with the APIs to find out the Data Saver status, that would require a `compileSdkVersion` compatible with Android N.

Comment: Thank you for helpful answer.

Comment: I decided let this network run on foreground service.